# M300 OSDK - drone version not obtained

Tags: dji-sdk

Since I cannot get the manifold 2 in my region, I created a cable according to https://forum.dji.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=219723.
The cable is connected via FTDI converter directly to the drone's OSDK port.
when connected to a serial terminal application I get data from the drone
[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMStj.png)

When I try to debug the flightcontrol-sample in Linux, I get the following:
[LinuxOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELwvK.png)

Data is also received in Linux using 'screen' command.
testing the cable for 'loopback' works fine.
I have changed the port baud rate to several options (230400 & 921600) to no avail.
the ACM cable is connected through an additional USB port to the drone's port directly.

Am I missing some HW components in my setup?

I have entered all the relevant Linux commands to get the required permissions as advised in
https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/quickstart/development-environment.html
&
https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/quickstart/run-the-sample.html

Am I missing something in that department?

The final goal is to use STM32 as FC, but testing is easier using the Linux environment.
Any additional things I can test?
Are there other working setup designs I can try?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

i got M300 osdk connection up at Apr 2020.

So far not many issues. There are many tricks and rules that you need to follows e.g  osdk adapter board usb type C seam side face inside. make sure osdk adapter board is powered up by checking the output supply voltage. 3.3V FTDI. and make sure it is pull up properly by checking voltage as well

After you check through the hardware.

the software has many tricks as well. for M300 only osdk/osdkros 4.0 and above can drive. The new userconfig.txt format changed and you have to change accordingly. and you can go through my checklist which I posted on DJI forum https://forum.dji.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=216529

If you really still have a problem. do provide photos on your connection, the terminal output for the error message.

Comment: Hi, I added more data in the post as an additional entry. Could you check it, please?

Answer (score 0):

As Dr. Yuan suggested, have a look at the UserConfig.txt file. Depending on which OSDK version you are using, it has a different format.
In my case, using osdk 3.9 configuring it this way solved my issues:
app_id : xxx (number)
app_key : xxx (number)
device : /dev/ttyUSB0
baudrate : 230400

Also check your FTDI cable, it once burned out for me and it was the reason for this error too. You should try a new one just in case.

I use the OSDK with a raspberry pi, in case you are using this kind of linux environment, I suggest you check the configuration files (cmdline.txt and config.txt) doing `sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt` and same for config.txt.
my configuration for cmdline.txt is:
`dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait`

And for config.txt just add this at the end:

```
enable_uart=1
init_uart_clock=64000000
start_x=1
```

I hope these can help and that I am not too late.